# how to speed up neural network performance in matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Using the neural network takes longer than training it. Am I doing something horribly wrong? 2 minutes to use vs 14 seconds to train.

```
load building_dataset % 4208 examples

inputs = buildingInputs; 
targets = buildingTargets;

% Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% Train the Network
tic
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
training_time = toc % ~= 14 seconds

% use the neural network
time = 0;
for i = 1:4208
  test_input = buildingInputs(:,i);
  tic
  test_output = net(test_input);
  time = time + toc;
end

time % ~= 117 seconds
average_time = time / 4208 % ~= 0.028 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to vectorize the input. Replace the for loop with this:

```
  test_input = buildingInputs(:,:);
  tic
  test_output = net(test_input);
  time = time + toc;
```

the output will be a matrix of results